# startActivity() from inside onPostExecute() not working

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I am doing an HttpPost to get data from a php server using async task.  Basically the php script will either return a JSON array or null.  It works fine when the json array is returned, however if the script returns null my if statement is not being picked up on and I am being returned this error:

Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray

This is a snippet of my script:

```
    @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            String url_select = "http://localhost/test.php";
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));
            try {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                //read content
                is =  httpEntity.getContent();  

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                }

            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = "";
                    while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                        sb.append(line+"\n");
                    }
                is.close();
                result=sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
            }
            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

        if(result == "null"){
         this.progressDialog.dismiss();
             startActivity(new Intent(viewRandom.this, allDone.class));
        }else{

        try {
            JSONArray Jarray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<Jarray.length();i++){
                JSONObject Jasonobject = null;
                Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = Jasonobject.getString("id");
        }
            this.progressDialog.dismiss();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: Change this if(result == "null") to if(result.equals("null")).

Comment: Can you tell us which line cause the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `if(result == "null")` to `if(result == null)`.

If you want to check for the string `"null"` do it with `.equals()`: `if ("null".equals(result))`

I am not sure if you really send a "null" string back from your server but anyway. As you might end returning `null` (not the string!), you should check for that, too.

Edit: Why is `"null".equals(result)` better than `result.equals("null")`? The answer is: the first one is null-safe which means it will not throw a NullPointerException when `result` is null. The second one will result in an exception in that case.

Comment: I have tried this and logcat is still throwing 06-17 10:38:20.173: E/log_tag(29836): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: Could you please update the code in your question to the current one? I guess you still have some error in the if clause as it goes into the else statement.

Comment: Actually this did just work.  I think it was a bad idea having my php script return the value "null" as a sting.  I changed the script so that it would return nothing and then set the if statement to: "".equals(result) and it works perfect.  Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning null Your Should try to return an Integer value to onPostExecute something like this

```
@Override
public Integer doInBackground(String...params){
    .......
    .......
    return 1;
}


protected void onPostExecute(Integer v) {
    if(v==1) {
    }
}
```